# Programatically grant "full control" to "everyone" on a registry key?

Tags: delphi, permissions, registry

I'm trying to figure out how to programatically grant "Everyone" "Full Control" over our software's registry key so non-administrators are able to write to it. However, I cannot find this, the only solution I have found is a third-party registry component that allows you to. I don't want to install a whole third-party library just to be able to do this. Is there perhaps a Windows API call I could make to do this?

This will be done inside a custom application installer of mine. Of course it would have to be done under elevated administrative access, which is another story.

Comment: I'm sure you are well aware that this very definitely considered bad practise. If you are trying to do this just locally on your own machines, then a PowerShell script is almost certainly the easiest way to automate.

Comment: Try the [`RegSetKeySecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: This is for an update utility for our software where customers have had it installed for many, many years, before that was necessary. Our *installer* does this, but our *updater* utility needs to do so as well.

Comment: If it's an installer why not use a PowerShell script?  Modern Windows versions include PowerShell already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you need is [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa379579.aspx). This topic on MSDN has sample code that will meet your needs: [Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283.aspx).

Comment: Awesome... Sadly I have yet to learn C++ and especially with Windows API (that's more code at that link than just one function call). Would you mind providing a Delphi example?

Comment: You don't need to know C++ to be able to translate that into Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - even it is easy to translate that example into Delphi, it is still a C++ example. And Jerry must handle the data type conversion, pointers,etc from C++ into Delphi. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @RBA It is my opinion that the skill of reading and translating C or C++ examples is essential for a Windows programmer. If you use a minority language like Delphi then you need also to understand the basics of the platform standard language.

Comment: @David I have to agree on that one. It's about time I take a crash-course in C++ anyway, because our company just purchased a VOIP system with an API entirely in C++, and I will be expected to write a Delphi wrapper for it :P

Comment: @JerryDodge Don't worry, translating between C and Delphi is cake, just google the commands that you're not sure about.

Comment: @Nortd I am actually, and have gotten stuck on `PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` which Microsoft claims there are many variations of it, but doesn't mention actually what the different variations are. Anyway, it's a necessary learning curve.

Comment: In the sample I linked to, the code doesn't need to know what pSD points to. It doesn't refer to pSD at all.

Comment: I recommend you just use the Jedi Security Api Library.

Comment: @Warren actually just downloaded it last night, have yet to get back to my IDE and jump into it

Answer (score 0):

For many years, our installer has shelled out to cacls to set permissions during installs.  It's been quite reliable.

Just figure out what command line arguments you need.

There's lots of documentation on this. For example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/windows-change-access-permissions-from-the-command-line.html